# how to setup PPPoE connection on android?

Tags: android, usb, ethernet, pppoe

I have an nexus 7 tablet with android 4.3. I have enabled pppoe and usbnet(for usb as ethernet port) in kernel. The ethernet over usb is working fine. Now I want to use pppoe through this UsbToEthernet port. Can anybody suggest how to proceed to connect to a ppp server from my android tablet?

Comment: Maybe, pppd daemon module has been disabled in 4.3 based on info in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.draisberghof.pppwidget&hl=en

Comment: @eee thanks for the info. But how can i know if the required drivers or modules are there in kernel or the user-space dependencies are there in android? at least could you please list the requirements for my android tablet to finish the above task?